# overlaying controls over videoview in avalonia

Tags: avaloniaui, libvlcsharp

i am currently trying to overlay controls over a videoview but can't seem to do so.

I've tried setting the zindex of the parent container (panel), but it does not seem to work.

I've seen this post [AvaloniaUI: Cannot embed VideoView control (LibVlcSharp) in a UserControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68292849/avaloniaui-cannot-embed-videoview-control-libvlcsharp-in-a-usercontrol) but i was wondering if anyone else here has managed to find another way workaround this current limitation, if so i would greatly appreciate the guidance/advice!

Comment: don't use axVLC, use libvlcsharp